# Table with composite primary key and version field in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa, jpa-2.1

I tried using @IdClass for this and regular @Version annotation on the version field but i keep getting the Error:

> OptimisticLockException: Attempted to attach deleted instance type "class xxx" with oid "xxx". If the instance is new, the version field should be left to its default value

After the EntityManager.merge(obj) line.
I have two PK's that are integers, so is the version field...
i use a PK- Class that has the Id fields with @IdClass(Pk.class) and the setter and getter for the Id's are calling an instance of the Pk class that is created in the constructor.
I'm not using @GeneratedId.
I'm using Openjpa not Hibernate.

Comment: Post actual classes and the code you use to get the error message. Without that it is hard to understand what you're doing ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your app. is changing version field. It should be never set. It is a technical column. Without pasting code here, is just a guess.

Comment: The setter for version is protected... Tried private as well. Im getting this after merge.

Comment: If you get an optimistic locking exception, it means that some other transaction has committed changes to entities you were trying to update/delete.

Comment: I figured out that although the setter for version is private there is a call Within the class itself for setVersion. Thank you for leading to the right direction.